# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable Python 3.7.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry guys for wasting your time with a newbie here. Today I ran at a problem . This is my code :

```
from turtle import *
shape("turtle")


def draw_square(length,color):

for i in range(4):
    forward(length)
    color('color')
    left(90)
return length,color



draw_square(100,'red')




mainloop()
```

The project is to draw a turlte square using function with 2 arguments : 'length' and 'color' . 15 mins ago I did succeeded in drawing correctly corresponding to the project requirements . After that , I re-ran the project again then this problem showed up . Im totally dead with this . Can u guys help me out please ? Thank you very much.

This is what VS said to me :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ex3.py", line 15, in <module>
draw_square(100,'red')
File "ex3.py", line 9, in draw_square
color('color')
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: The indentation didn't throw an error?

Comment: are you sure your code is correctly indented? also, what line is the error being produced at?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you also include the `turtle` module? It is difficult to figure out what is wrong with your code when here is not enough information (even `str` does not exist within the current snippet). Also, please fix the indentation of your code since it is crucial in python

Comment: I've added to my topic , you guys can check above

Comment: Please add `turtle` module which is containing `color`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`color` is a local variable (that is provided as an argument) in the `draw_square` function. You pass a string (`'red'`) as said argument and then call it as if it were a function

```
color('color')  # color == 'red', so 'red'('color') is tried here
```

You can avoid that by not shadowing the turtle function `color` in `draw_square`:

```
def draw_square(length, given_color):
    for i in range(4):
        forward(length)
        color(given_color)  # color here will be the actual function from turtle
        left(90)
    return length, given_color
```

Comment: Omg it works . Thank you so much . So the problem is just about the name of the argument right ? It took me hours yesterday and i didnt find any solution on google :(

Comment: @That's how we remember best ;-)

Comment: @AnhMinh If you use a good IDE (e.g. PyCharm) and generally not use `*` imports, you will always be warned if you shadow names.

Comment: Thats why all my projects which use * imports have red title right ?

Comment: Right. To cite the [Style Guide for Python Code (PEP-8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): "Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools."